# how to use sinhala unicode for suggestions in EditText in android

Tags: android, unicode, android-edittext, search-suggestion, google-input-tools

I'm creating an android app that is totally Sinhala. I want to enable users to type Singlish in the application and suggest related Sinhala letters according to user typed Singlish word. like google input tools does. what's the process to accomplish this.

refer to the below image for better understanding.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTbXY.png)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages